# Rails 4.1.7 bootstrap-sass fails to load with Undefined mixin 'border-radius'.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, bootstrap-sass

I upgraded from 3.2 to Rails 4.1.7 and I get the following error:

```
 Undefined mixin 'border-radius'.
```

I can change my imports after bootstrap and get:

```
 Undefined variable: "$baseLineHeight".
```

It looks to me like I am not loading my bootstrap mixins and variables

So I believe that I am not loading the bootstrap variables and mixins and it crashes on the first variable or mixin to load

My Application.css.scss

```
@import "bourbon";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "chosen";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "navbar";
@import "visits";
@import "oc";
```

Gemfile

```
gem "bourbon"
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 4.0.0'
```

All my files are css.scss  and not css

I get the same errors when I try to precompile my assets

Any answers or debugging tips?